# Facebook's "signed_request" is empty when first starting app

Tags: php, facebook, oauth-2.0

I had to add Facebook Credits to my app, in order to do that I had to activate "OAuth 2.0 for Canvas", which is supposed to send a signed_request to my app

But I noticed that when I first start the app after not using it for a while (or in a different browser), signed_request is empty. If I reload the page, then its there. But the first time, its always empty. I use $_REQUEST['signed_request'] to get it.

My guess is that this has to be somehow related with cookies or session expiring.

Any ideas?

Comment: I've found something that might help: the first time the app is called, it does get the signed request. BUT, then, require_login() forces the page to reload, and when it reloads, signed_request is empty. This only happens if you havent used the app for a while, or if you remove the cookies. And btw I had to use a special version of require_login to prevent it from redirecting to my hosting url (instead of the app url)... I got the trick from here http://www.foobots.net/breakouts.html (iframe_require_login)

Comment: So far I guess the only solution is to just use the GRAPH api for everything and get rid of the REST api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: signed_request WAS being sent when opening the app. But then require_login() was causing a page reload (not always, but sometimes) and then signed_request was being lost, causing the illusion that signed_request was not being sent at all.

Solution: I replaced all REST api calls with GRAPH api calls.

Hope this information is useful to someone!

Answer (score 3):

On your app settings, be sure to put trailing slash - "/" on your app path (or tab URL). Leave other settings to their default values.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not sure if this is relevant now that I'm using the GRAPH api instead of REST, but probably it'll be of help to other people.